# Constructive proof that $\liminf na_n = 0$ if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, constructive-mathematics

As stated in this question [If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\liminf na_n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122778/if-sum-a-n-converges-then-liminf-na-n-0), the proof in the title can be proven if it can be shown that there is a subsequence of $na_n$ that converges to 0. I was curious if anyone can provide a witness for this statement. The answer given in the linked question is a contradiction argument.

Edit: The sequence $a_n$ is positive. I already know that this is true and understand the non-constructive proof for it, but I was wondering if anyone could provide a proof that involves actually constructing a subsequence of $na_n$ that converges to 0.

Comment: By "witness" you mean an example?

Comment: Maybe not a specific example, but an algorithm for producing such a sequence would suffice

Comment: @DonAntonio You only need positive. For if $\liminf_n a_n=\alpha>0$, then $\sum_n a_n\ge c+\frac\alpha2\sum_n\frac1n=\infty$.

Comment: If the series converges, its terms **must** decrease to $0$.  But you do need absolute convergence to be sure this is true, as the alternating harmonic series demonstrates.

Comment: Perhaps my edit will clarify the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @DonAntonio The conversation has been about $\liminf$ all along.

Comment: @Gae.S. Ah, that is true. Thanks, deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\inf_{n+1 \leq p \leq 2n}\,pa_p \leq 2n\inf_{n+1 \leq p \leq 2n}\,a_p \leq 2\sum_{p=n+1}^{2n}{a_p}.$$

As a consequence, $$\inf_{k \geq n+1}\,ka_k \leq 2\sum_{k > n}{a_k},$$ which proves the conclusion.